# Netbeans and SQL connection Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'

Im getting this error when I try to connect netbeans to mysql. I researched some solution and I tried to change my Connection/J driver to the latest version and now I'm getting this error.

2021-02-04T02:55:40.954709Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 3136
2021-02-04T02:55:41.147799Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-02-04T02:55:41.147990Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-02-04T02:55:41.233435Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2021-02-04T02:55:41.305987Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-02-04T02:55:41.358624Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i122z.png)

Need some suggestion on how to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your data directory is missing. Which is very unrelated to the `Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'` problem. Did you not install it, did you remove it?

Comment: I did not remove anything in my data. At first i tried to change my Connector/J multiple times and after there an error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:NO)

Comment: After i enter my password im getting java.math.biginteger cannot be casted to java.lang.long

Comment: That's either a netbeans or Connector/J bug. Try the connector/J connecting in a different way using something else. The stack of that exception would be useful. The text log above shows the server not starting, so it looks like two separate issues are being posted.